# Google App Engine modules: routing second module to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, module, url-routing, google-cloud-platform

Has anyone run two different WordPress installations as separate modules inside Google App Engine?

I have the following:

```
/app/
    - wordpress1
    - wordpress2
    - app.yaml
    - second.yaml
    - dispatch.yaml
    - php.ini
```

Inside `wordpress1` and `wordpress2` are somewhat clean installations of WordPress, with some GAE helper plugins.

`app.yaml` contains the default module config, which redirects traffic to `wordpress1` using URL handlers.

`second.yaml` contains the second module config (`module: second`) and redirects traffic to `wordpress2`.

In dispatch.yaml I only check for a subdir second to load the `second.yaml` config:

```
dispatch:
    - url: "*/second*"
      module: second
```

Everything is fine and dandy:

```
http://localhost.dev:8080 -> wordpress1/index.php
http://localhost.dev:8080/second/ -> wordpress2/index.php
```

But I can't seem to work out how to set the edge cases:

```
http://localhost.dev:8080/secondwithextra -> dispatcher error (no URL set)
http://localhost.dev:8080/second (missing trailing slash) -> same as above
```

I tried to add the following to `second.yaml` handlers:

```
- url: /second[^/].+/?
  script: wordpress1/index.php # Reroute to `wordpress1` because not a directory match.
```

But that didn't really work out.

How can I make the second module accept request URI `/second`, `/second/`, `/second/abc` but not `/secondxyz`?

Having the `dispatch.yaml` URL glob set to `*/second/*` breaks the slashless `/second`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to add both `*/second/*` and `/second` in dispatch.yaml.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow and see what happens. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. When I add `/second` (no wildcards) the GAE SDK complains it is not a usable `url` value. Adding `*/second` seems to make no difference either to the slashless dispatching.

Comment: Sorry,  I meant  '/second*' first, or whichever works for everything but the '/second' url. As for the '/second' url itself, you may need a rule for it specifically in the module, not 100% sure, I have to check.